# multiple threads injecting data into the subsequent process

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a project made using Java.

I have a complex processing, something like from one single process i create 10 different threads, then the process waits for the other threads to complete processing. Now the threads that were created do some database processsing, and then finally generates the output. But the problem here is, the process that have been waiting, again needs to process all the data that was created in the threads that were created, sort of aggregated result.

I am almost clueless what needs to be done.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue.  Have each thread put their results on the queue when they're done.  The main thread just watches the queue and processes the results as they come in.

Another alternative is to use Futures.  Instead of threads just use Futures for each of the processes.  The main thread will block while waiting for each future to finish it's processing.

Comment: in this case how the main process will know that the other threads have completed working??

Comment: If you're watching a queue, then either you have to know how many things are expected or the process has to put some kind of marker on the queue saying it's complete.

Comment: In the case of futures, you just call future.get() and it waits until the thread delivers the result.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) to aggregate all your data in one data structure.

This queue can then be used by your main process (even before all your threads actually finished their work).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to start 10 threads in your main thread, and wait for them to finish. This can be done calling [`Thread.join()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) on each of the 10 started threads (after they are all started).

For more information about threads, read [the Java tutorial about concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Answer (score 0):

If your difficulty is how to wait in the main thread until child threads complete their work , then you can use `childThread.join()` on child threads from the main thread.  If you are troubled by how to make the results brought by the child threads from db availble to the main thread for processing , then use some shared data structure which is populated by the child threads and which is then accessed by the main thread. ( Make sure you synchronize properly )

For all such tasks however , it is best to use `Executor` framework in Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a shared object to add data to it.

If I understand right then:

Create a class that will hold all data in the end (for example MyData). This class could have "getData" method that will return data and "add" method which will add data to some collection of your choice (array, list, ...).

Then when a thread is done with processing the data it calls:

```
MyData.add(partialDataFromThread)
```

And in the end your main class will do:

```
MainClass.process(MyData.getDatA());
```

Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.util.concurrent.CompletionService to submit and poll for the task completion.

Alternatively look into CountdownLatch or the CyclicBarrier classes.

Let me know if you need examples because I assume internet would already be flooded with such examples; also the javadocs are pretty good and it is always a good learning curve to do it first hand.